# How to programmatically change the state of all objects of a folder?

Tags: plone, archetypes, plone-4.x

How can I programmatically change the state of all objects in a folder to 'published'?
All are default objects of Plone 4 as Link, Page, Document, and so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cycle all objects in that folder and publish them:

```
wftool = getToolByName(folder, 'portal_workflow')
for child in folder.objectValues():
    wftool.doActionFor(child, 'publish')
```

Comment: and usually `child.reindexObject()`!

Comment: actually, you have to check for each object which workflow is on; then is useful to wrap the doActionFor() action in a try/except block too: some content may already have been published. I'm sure here ( http://developer.plone.org/content/workflow.html#changing-workflow-state ) you may found all what you needs.